# Rewrite the scaffolding files generated by yeoman according to the .editorconfig file

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

When I install an app with `yo` command, the generated files have “indent size” equal to two.

I would like to change the default “indent size” editing the .editorconfig and then rewriting all files according the new .editorconfig parameter.

How should be possible to get it?